# jade extends and include not working together

Tags: pug

I'm having a problem that if I use an `include` after and `extends` the blocks in the included file do not get used.

```
//layout.jade
block content

//entry.jade
extends layout
case form
  when 'special'
    include special
  default
    include generic

//generic.jade/special.jade
block content
  Generic Content
```

When I do this the content from the included file is not actually used. If I instead put the "extends" inside the included file it works, but I don't want to do this.

Am I doing something wrong or is this unsupported?

Comment: May be your problem: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/997

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Couple of things here.

An include is not for a block, it's just code. You can find the whole [include doc here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a13).

So the generic.jade/specific.jade should only be the jade code, but no `block content`.

And you'll maybe gonna have to indent the `case form` after the `extends layout`.